# Produce Messages to RabbitMQ with random but continuous values from 0 to 100 usingPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I am very new to RabbitMq and really need to understand how to do it with Python. Because from the tutorial I only wrote the code below which only sends 'hello world!' as a string:

```
import pika
import random

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue="hello")

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='hello world!')
print(" [x] Sent 'hello world!'")
connection.close()
```

But I need to produce messages to the broker with random but continuous values from 0 to 100. Can someone help me with what should I add to the code above to do this???? Or any tutorial advice for me?
Thx from now..

Comment: Like `[0,1,2,3..100]` or 1 and second message 2 and 3 ..

Comment: This is your sender code which is saying that send the body('hello world" to the queue whose name is hello . Now you need to write the reciver code which will recive the message from sender

Comment: Hi, like 1 and second message 2 and 3..

Comment: as receiver
'''
import pika
import sys

def main():
    connection =pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

    def callback(body):
        print(" [x] Rcvd %r" % body.decode())

    channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    channel.start_consuming()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('interrupted')
'''

Comment: But I do not want to send a string, I  want to send a "random but continuous values"

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is what exactly I tried to ask and need !! :)

Comment: Oh no, it gave me an error as:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Also this:
    if newnumber>previous:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: Hi, no I directly paste your source code :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pika
from random import randint 

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')
)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue="hello")

previous=0
while True:
    newnumber=randint(previous+1, 100)
    if newnumber>previous:
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body=str(newnumber))
        print(f" [x] Sent {newnumber}")
        previous=newnumber
    if newnumber==100:
        break

connection.close()
```

I think *random but continues* means this:
`[5,34,78,99,100]` creating every number randomly but in continuous order. Another example is `[45,60,77,78,83,89,96,98,100]`

Comment: please look for the next comment I took a ss you can see my error msg with the code

Comment: @HandeYildirim I have edited the answer, it's not big issue it's we are calculating newnumber as integer but that pika doesn't support integer, it only supports string. So, I converted interger to string. By doing str(newnumber). And yeah! Sorry, my bad. And where are you getting _TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int_  error?

Comment: Hi, yes its working now and no more error :) thank you, also I want to ask in the example that I am working now, it says "continuous values". Does it mean that sender should always send a value? If yes should I remove connection.close() part or if newnumber>previous: statement to do this ?

Comment: I didn't understand clearly what you are trying to ask? Please try again. :( are you asking that how `if newnumber>previous` works?

Comment: No, I need to create smt calling 'meter'. This should produce messages to the RabbitMq with random but continuous values from 0 to 100 Watts. This is to mock a regular home power consumption.

Comment: That is why I am asking the before question

Comment: That if condition, is just checking if newnumber is greater then previous one or not cuz we need contionus but we are taking randomly. So, we have to check it.